# Скрытие и вывод враппера в реакте

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Коллеги, помогите пожалуйста начинающему в реакт разобраться в следующем вопросе: как можно в следующем примере скрывать или выводить `<ComponentWrapper>` при помощи пропсы?
То есть, есть некое приложение за работу которого отвечает некий `<Component/>` и по умолчанию мне обёртка над ним не нужна. Но в определённых ситуациях - на страницах, где этот компонент не может быть без данного враппера нужно её подключать.

```
const App = () {
  return (
    <ComponentWrapper>
      <Component/>
    </ComponentWrapper>
  );
}
```

Сам компонент выводится в другом месте и хотелось бы получить удобный функционал вроде:

```
<App isWrapper />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```js
const Span = ({text}) => (<span>{text}</span>)

const ConditionalWrapper = ({isWrapper}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {
        isWrapper ?
        <div class='wrapper'>
          <Span text={'With wrapper'}/>
        </div> :
        <Span text={'Without wrapper'}/>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ConditionalWrapper isWrapper={true}/>
      <ConditionalWrapper isWrapper={false}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```